# Mathematica 12.1 is treating all my cells as raw texts by default

Tags: front-end, cells, stylesheet, configuration, default

I was once using Mathematica 11 it all works fine - when I create new Notebook (.nb) input like `1+1` and press `shift`+`enter`, it shows `output[1]:= 2` directly

But now for 12.1 when I create new notebook and do the same thing, it is treating my input `1+1` as plain text by default, when i press `shift`+`enter` there is just a linebreak.. no evaluation at all.

I find when I go to the menu -> cell -> cell properties    and tick *Evaluatable* then the input  can work well as Mathematica 11. BUT when i input `Plot[x,{x,1,2}]`, it gives output `-Graphics-`!! Without showing what the graphic is! I then have to manually convert the  output cell to StandardForm to show the graph! I have to do such things everytime, why is 12.1 getting me so much ados ..and how can i remove such tedious things  making it funcation just like what mathematica 11 does?

Pardon me I'm a complete nooooooob and really searched goooogle tons of times not getting the answer....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These strange behaviors can be produced by:

1. `` SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], FrontEnd`ReturnCreatesNewCell -> True] `` (or, in MMA 12+, just `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], ReturnCreatesNewCell -> True]`since `ReturnCreatesNewCell` is now defined in the `` System` ``  namespace).
2. `SetOptions[$Output, FormatType -> OutputForm]` or `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CommonDefaultFormatTypes->{"Output"->StandardForm}]`

It's quite strange for a new Wolfram Mathematica installation to be like this. I'm not sure which situation you are in and whether there are other problems.

If you haven't made any major changes from a new installation, then I think the problem is likely due to the stylesheet. Try to set the stylesheet of the notebook to `Default`.

Comment: Its true the stylesheet everything going back2 normal when set to default... .thx

Comment: I am confused about your statement about `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CommonDefaultFormatTypes->{"Output"->StandardForm}]`, it has two meanings. Do you mean that (a) the `CommonDefaultFormatTypes` defines _no other options except_ `"Output"`, or (b) That the `CommonDefaultFormatTypes` option list _contains_ `"Output"->StandardForm` among other rules? (b) is the default in MMA 12.x and 13. Also, IMO, it would be a bit clearer if you could provided non-destructive queries the OP could perform, e.g. `Options[EvaluationNotebook[], ReturnCreatesNewCell]` for the item 1, etc.

Comment: @kkm My aim is to make minimal change to the system, so I've used the nested syntax of queries.